# Programming my first app in Swift - "error: attach by pid '2423' failed -- unable to attach"

Tags: xcode

When I go to run my first program in Swift (I have only been studying the language for about a month - my first programming language), I receive the error: "error: attach by pid '2423' failed -- unable to attach".  Here is my code if anyone can point out the problem for me. This is also my first question in Stackoverflow, so please let me know if this is an appropriate question. Thanks!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameDisplayed: UILabel!

    @IBAction func submitButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        nameText.text = nameDisplayed.text
    }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: I sometimes get odd error messages like this when I connect a dead phone to use for testing.  Once it gets enough charge, I need to unplug it and then plug it back into the computer.

Comment: Try resetting your 'Content and Settings' for your device if you're using a simulator. Also, you can try cleaning the project and rebuilding. I don't really see anything wrong with the code as long as the outlet's are all properly linked.

Comment: Thanks for both of your thoughts.  I tried the reset under "Content and Settings," but now when I run it, I now just get a blank iPhone screen in the Xcode simulator (but no error message).  So I guess I'm one step closer....